# Input attachment from previous subpass in Vulkan

Tags: vulkan

I am trying to first render some content to an R8_UNORM image view in subpass 0, and then use the result as an input attachment in subpass 1, using `subpassLoad` in the fragment shader. However, the final output from the render pass (which is also the swapchain image(s) that is presented) contains garbage (see https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRC6Y.jpg) using the following fragment shader:

```
#version 420
layout(input_attachment_index=0, set=0, binding=0) uniform subpassInput input_text;
layout(location=0) out vec4 color;
void main()
{
    float value = subpassLoad(input_text).r;
    if (value > 0.0f) {
        color = vec4(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    }
}
```

Yet, using this fragment shader:

```
#version 420
layout(input_attachment_index=0, set=0, binding=0) uniform subpassInput input_text;
layout(location=0) out vec4 color;
void main()
{
    float value = subpassLoad(input_text).r;
    if (value > 0.0f) {
        color = vec4(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    }
    else {
        color = vec4(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    }
}
```

gives me the expected results (see https://i.stack.imgur.com/eje0S.jpg), so I'm suspecting some synchronization issue that isn't present when each fragment is written to.

The clear values used for the two framebuffer attachments are as follows:

```
VkClearColorValue black_clear_color = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f };
VkClearColorValue red_clear_color = { 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };
VkClearValue clear_value[2];
clear_value[0].color = vk_black_clear_color; // R8_UNORM attachment
clear_value[1].color = vk_red_clear_color; // Swapchain attachment
```

with the fragment shader for subpass 0 always writing `1.0f` to each fragment it is to shade.

Here's what I deem to be the relevant code:

**Command buffer recording, submission, and image presentation**

```
// Record
vkCmdBeginRenderPass(command_buffer, &render_pass_begin_info, VK_SUBPASS_CONTENTS_INLINE);
vkCmdBindPipeline(command_buffer, VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS, text_graphics_pipeline);
vkCmdBindVertexBuffers(command_buffer, 0, 1, &text_vertex_buffer, &vertex_buffer_offset);
vkCmdDraw(command_buffer, 15, 1, 0, 0);
vkCmdNextSubpass(command_buffer, VK_SUBPASS_CONTENTS_INLINE);
vkCmdBindPipeline(command_buffer, VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS, final_graphics_pipeline);
vkCmdBindDescriptorSets(command_buffer, VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS, final_pipeline_layout, 0, 1, &final_descriptor_set, 0, NULL);
vkCmdBindVertexBuffers(command_buffer, 0, 1, &final_vertex_buffer, &vertex_buffer_offset);
vkCmdDraw(command_buffer, 6, 1, 0, 0);
vkCmdEndRenderPass(command_buffer);
CHECK_VK_RES(vkEndCommandBuffer(command_buffer));

// Submit
VkPipelineStageFlags pipeline_wait_stages = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT;
VkSubmitInfo submit_info;
submit_info.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_SUBMIT_INFO;
submit_info.pNext = NULL;
submit_info.waitSemaphoreCount = 1;
submit_info.pWaitSemaphores = &swapchain_image_avilable_semaphore;
submit_info.pWaitDstStageMask = &pipeline_wait_stages;
submit_info.commandBufferCount = 1;
submit_info.pCommandBuffers = &command_buffer;
submit_info.signalSemaphoreCount = 1;
submit_info.pSignalSemaphores = &command_buffer_finished_semaphore;
CHECK_VK_RES(vkQueueSubmit(queue, 1, &submit_info, command_buffer_finished_fence));

// Present
VkPresentInfoKHR present_info;
present_info.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PRESENT_INFO_KHR;
present_info.pNext = NULL;
present_info.waitSemaphoreCount = 1;
present_info.pWaitSemaphores = &command_buffer_finished_semaphore;
present_info.swapchainCount = 1;
present_info.pSwapchains = &swapchain;
present_info.pImageIndices = &image_available_idx;
present_info.pResults = NULL;
CHECK_VK_RES(vkQueuePresentKHR(queue, &present_info));
```

**Render Pass Setup**

```
// Render pass attachments
VkAttachmentDescription vk_render_pass_attachment_descriptions[2];
// Text attachment
render_pass_attachment_descriptions[0].flags = 0;
render_pass_attachment_descriptions[0].format = VK_FORMAT_R8_UNORM;
render_pass_attachment_descriptions[0].samples = VK_SAMPLE_COUNT_1_BIT;
render_pass_attachment_descriptions[0].loadOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_CLEAR;
render_pass_attachment_descriptions[0].storeOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_STORE;
render_pass_attachment_descriptions[0].stencilLoadOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_DONT_CARE;
render_pass_attachment_descriptions[0].stencilStoreOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_DONT_CARE;
render_pass_attachment_descriptions[0].initialLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED;
render_pass_attachment_descriptions[0].finalLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_SHADER_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL;
// Final attachment
render_pass_attachment_descriptions[1].flags = 0;
render_pass_attachment_descriptions[1].format = swapchain_format; // BGRA8_UNORM
render_pass_attachment_descriptions[1].samples = VK_SAMPLE_COUNT_1_BIT;
render_pass_attachment_descriptions[1].loadOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_CLEAR;
render_pass_attachment_descriptions[1].storeOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_STORE;
render_pass_attachment_descriptions[1].stencilLoadOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_DONT_CARE;
render_pass_attachment_descriptions[1].stencilStoreOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_DONT_CARE;
render_pass_attachment_descriptions[1].initialLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED;
render_pass_attachment_descriptions[1].finalLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_PRESENT_SRC_KHR;

// Subpass descriptions
VkSubpassDescription render_pass_subpass_descriptions[2];
// Subpass 0
VkAttachmentReference text_subpass_color_attachment_reference;
text_subpass_color_attachment_reference.attachment = 0;
text_subpass_color_attachment_reference.layout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL;
render_pass_subpass_descriptions[0].flags = 0;
render_pass_subpass_descriptions[0].pipelineBindPoint = VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS;
render_pass_subpass_descriptions[0].inputAttachmentCount = 0;
render_pass_subpass_descriptions[0].pInputAttachments = NULL;
render_pass_subpass_descriptions[0].colorAttachmentCount = 1;
render_pass_subpass_descriptions[0].pColorAttachments = &text_subpass_color_attachment_reference;
render_pass_subpass_descriptions[0].pResolveAttachments = NULL;
render_pass_subpass_descriptions[0].pDepthStencilAttachment = NULL;
render_pass_subpass_descriptions[0].preserveAttachmentCount = 0;
render_pass_subpass_descriptions[0].pPreserveAttachments = NULL;
// Subpass 1
VkAttachmentReference final_subpass_input_attachment_reference;
final_subpass_input_attachment_reference.attachment = 0;
final_subpass_input_attachment_reference.layout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_SHADER_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL;
VkAttachmentReference final_subpass_color_attachment_reference;
final_subpass_color_attachment_reference.attachment = 1;
final_subpass_color_attachment_reference.layout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL;
render_pass_subpass_descriptions[1].flags = 0;
render_pass_subpass_descriptions[1].pipelineBindPoint = VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS;
render_pass_subpass_descriptions[1].inputAttachmentCount = 1;
render_pass_subpass_descriptions[1].pInputAttachments = &final_subpass_input_attachment_reference;
render_pass_subpass_descriptions[1].colorAttachmentCount = 1;
render_pass_subpass_descriptions[1].pColorAttachments = &final_subpass_color_attachment_reference;
render_pass_subpass_descriptions[1].pResolveAttachments = NULL;
render_pass_subpass_descriptions[1].pDepthStencilAttachment = NULL;
render_pass_subpass_descriptions[1].preserveAttachmentCount = 0;
render_pass_subpass_descriptions[1].pPreserveAttachments = NULL;

// Subpass dependencies
VkSubpassDependency renderpass_subpass_dependencies[2];
// Ensure subpass 1's color attachment (swapchain image) is transitioned before it's written to
// since the pWaitDstStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT
renderpass_subpass_dependencies[0].srcSubpass = VK_SUBPASS_EXTERNAL;
renderpass_subpass_dependencies[0].srcStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT;
renderpass_subpass_dependencies[0].srcAccessMask = 0;
renderpass_subpass_dependencies[0].dstSubpass = 1;
renderpass_subpass_dependencies[0].dstStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT;
renderpass_subpass_dependencies[0].dstAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_WRITE_BIT;
renderpass_subpass_dependencies[0].dependencyFlags = 0;
// Subpass 1 cannot read from its input attachment before subpass 0 finishes writing to its color attachment
renderpass_subpass_dependencies[1].srcSubpass = 0;
renderpass_subpass_dependencies[1].srcStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT;
renderpass_subpass_dependencies[1].srcAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_WRITE_BIT;
renderpass_subpass_dependencies[1].dstSubpass = 1;
renderpass_subpass_dependencies[1].dstStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_FRAGMENT_SHADER_BIT;
renderpass_subpass_dependencies[1].dstAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_INPUT_ATTACHMENT_READ_BIT;
renderpass_subpass_dependencies[1].dependencyFlags = 0;

// Render pass
VkRenderPassCreateInfo render_pass_info;
render_pass_info.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_RENDER_PASS_CREATE_INFO;
render_pass_info.pNext = NULL;
render_pass_info.flags = 0;
render_pass_info.attachmentCount = 2;
render_pass_info.pAttachments = render_pass_attachment_descriptions;
render_pass_info.subpassCount = 2;
render_pass_info.pSubpasses = render_pass_subpass_descriptions;
render_pass_info.dependencyCount = 2;
render_pass_info.pDependencies = renderpass_subpass_dependencies;
VkRenderPass render_pass;
CHECK_VK_RES(vkCreateRenderPass(vk_device, &render_pass_info, NULL, &render_pass));
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I can't seem to see what's wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The synchronization was not the culprit here. Rather, it was the fact that the `out vec4 color` from subpass 1 was always written out to the framebuffer (as the geometry is a full-screen quad), even though it wasn't initialized to anything if the if-condition wasn't satisfied.

By adding a `discard` to the shader in the else-clause, the correct output is obtained:

```
#version 420
layout(input_attachment_index=0, set=0, binding=0) uniform subpassInput input_text;
layout(location=0) out vec4 color;
void main()
{
    float value = subpassLoad(input_text).r;
    if (value > 0.0f) {
        color = vec4(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    }
    else {
        discard;
    }
}
```

As an "fun" fact: the reason the incorrect image in the question isn't very blue in the top-left corner, but is blue for most of the rest of the image is probably that the registers that are used to store the values in `color` are re-used. So in the beginning (assuming the work starts from the top-left corner), the registers contain garbage, but as actual blue fragments are written out, more and more registers have old blue values in them. Therefore, when the else-clause is active, blue is written out, even though its technically garbage.